# avoid insert varchar string in a INT field mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table:

```
id int
user_id int
date datetime
```

what happens is, if I insert a varchar string in user_id, mysql insert this field setting it to 0.

Can I prevent this insert in mysql? if it is a string, do not convert to 0 and insert.

Comment: no. If the field is set to `INT` than the only thing allowed, no characters.

Comment: @CodeGodie ok, but I want to avoid the insert. If I sent a string, mysql insert it anyway... but it converts my string to 0 and insert. I want to avoid this insert, I don't want 0 there.

Comment: I am not sure if MySQL provides such an option, generally it is better to sanitize your inputs as much as possible before it gets that far.

Comment: yea Mysql does not do that. You would need to change your database to Postgres or perhaps Oracle.. If you want to still work with Mysql than you would need to do the sanitation prior sending data to it.

Comment: oh, ok! thank you friends! It is easy to sanitize... I just want to know if I could let it to mysql! thank you

Comment: When you say "If I insert" you mean how? Is this done via some application programming layer, like PHP or Java?

Comment: yeah, it is PHP. So user can fake the form value and send a string instead of int... but in php I can check it easily. @tadman just ask to know if I could avoid the manual check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an opportunity to process and validate values before they're inserted in the database, do it there. Don't think of these checks as "manual", that's absurd. They're necessary, and it's a standard practice.

MySQL's philosophy is "do what I mean" which often leads to trouble like this. If you supply a string for an integer field it will do its best to convert it, and in the case of invalid numbers it will simply cast to `0` as that the closest it can get. It also quietly truncates string fields that are too long, for example, as if you cared about the additional data you would've made your column bigger.

This is the polar opposite of many other databases that are extremely picky about the type of data that can be inserted.

Comment: thank you for your answer! Yeah, mysql provides some commands as unique to avoid duplications, foreign key(references) to avoid irrelevant data... could provide some to avoid string insert in a int field! but you are totally right!

Comment: MySQL's answer in this case is "Ehhhh" so if you need a database that's more particular and cantankerous, you may need to switch to a different one. PostgreSQL, as an example, will freak out over the slightest thing, which means you can't get away with this sort of casual mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

If the `int` column(s) are not nullable, something like this **might** work as a filter (depending on settings, MySQL might just convert the NULL to 0):

```
INSERT INTO theTable(intField) 
VALUES (IF(CAST(CAST('[thevalue]' AS SIGNED) AS CHAR) = '[thevalue]', '[thevalue]', NULL))
;
```